# Excel MERP Crash?

Tags: ms-office, crash, macos

Does anybody have issues with Excel or any other office applications when opening them? Module 'merp' causes office apps to crash. Have you found a fix to this?

Office 2016, macOS Sierra Public Beta 1 (16A238m)

```
Microsoft Error Reporting log version: 2.0

Error Signature:
Exception: 
Date/Time: 2016-07-30 01:10:09 +0000
Application Name: Microsoft Excel
Application Bundle ID: com.microsoft.Excel
Application Signature: XCEL
Application TimeStamp: 0x5593ed3d
Application Version: 15.11.2.150701
Crashed Module Name: merp
Crashed Module Version: 15.11.2.150701
Crashed Module Offset: 0x00003365
Blame Module Name: MicrosoftSetupUI
Blame Module Version: 15.11.2.150701
Blame Module TimeStamp: 0x56768edf
Blame Module Offset: 0x0000000000013dc1
StachHash: 74f9
Application LCID: 1033
Extra app info: Reg=en Loc=0x0409
Crashed thread: 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real cause of your error is hidden because the error reporting module itself also crashes (merp is Microsoft's error reporting module).

You want to first disable MERP, then you would get a better error description for the actual cause of the problem.

You can disable MERP like this:

1. Using Finder, browse to the folder: /Library/Application Support/Microsoft/MERP2.0
2. Double-click Microsoft Error Reporting
3. In Preferences: Uncheck "Enable Microsoft Error Reporting"

Comment: Well that didn't changed the error but right now I'm updating excel from auto update and I'll report you tomorrow for any news.

Comment: update solved it

Comment: On the offchance that you are reading this, I cannot locate the *MERP* file in that folder or anywhere else on my system (according to system search). Is this in a different spot? (Sierra 10.12, Excel for Mac 15.39). Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "system search", but use the method I described to use the folder instead of searching. On my system (newest Office version available), the folder is still in the same location.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and no one at Apple or Microsoft could resolve it. I stumbled upon a patch from Microsoft after various Google searches:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3187505

The file is under manual updates:

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=525133

A similar answer is provided on the SuperUser exchange [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1127350/fix-microsoft-excel-and-powerpoint-crash-in-macos-sierra-10-12):